# Am I loading this Music correctly with Bass.dll?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, ogg, bass

Based on Bass's documentation, I'm trying to load an ogg file with the code that follows:

```
var
  FFile : string;
  Music: HSAMPLE; 
  ch: HCHANNEL;
  OpenDialog1 : TOpenDialog;
begin
  Dynamic_Bass.Load_BASSDLL('Library/Bass.dll');
  Dynamic_Bass.BASS_Init(1,44000,Bass_DEVICE_SPEAKERS,0,nil);  
  OpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
    Exit;
  ffile := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  Music := BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, PChar(ffile), 0, 0, 3, BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS);
  ch := BASS_SampleGetChannel(Music, False);
  BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_PAN, 0);
  BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, 1);
  BASS_ChannelPlay(ch, False);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(BASS_ErrorGetCode));
end;
```

`ShowMessage` returns 5. Acording to documentation this is Handle error, what means that the error is in the `music` var. If I comment the lines below `BASS_SampleLoad` I get error 2. Means the file could not be loaded. So it is an ordinary OGG file. So my question: Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't appear to be checking the return values of the functions that you call

Comment: @David they aren't util here at all. (I guess)

Comment: You have to use the library properly. I for one won't attempt to help until you implement proper error checking. Chuck Norris can get away with not checking return values. The rest of us? Not so much.

Comment: **Please** use a `try..finally` together with your open dialog!!

Comment: I wish I knew **what** returns `5`. "It" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Presumably `bass_errorgetcode` returns 5. But who knows which API call failed? Because without real error checking we cannot know.

Comment: @David Yes, I gathered that `bass_errorgetcode` was the subject, just making sure OP realized that they must write things in a way that us readers can understand.

Comment: What's the deal with the cross posting? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6778/estou-carregando-essa-musica-corretamente-com-a-bass-dll

Comment: SO Fellows, I don't agree with the close votes on this one, The OP supplied enough information to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I didn't vote for the question its self or to close. I agree OP supplied enough information, just the style of the OP's code points out many shortcomings.

Comment: @whosrdaddy "hey aren't util here at all. (I guess)". The asker explicitly refused to perform the error checking that would have narrowed the question down. As such the down votes and close votes were correctly cast in my view. When the asker is not prepared to listen to advice it is reasonable to object.

Comment: @whos - Maybe close as duplicate of the one on the pt site?

Comment: I did wrong by ask at PTs too? Beacuse I thought the audience would variate a bit from here to there.

Comment: @Guill: I understand why you did this but I can imagine that some people may get offended, I understand you are not an english native speaker (me neither ;)) and you seek help in your native language. Do realize though that most if not all the Delphi legends (no I'm not part of this group :)) reside on the english forum ;)

Comment: @whosrdaddy I just read this by Stack Team: "we expect almost every question asked on the Portuguese site to also be asked (and answered) on the English site" Maybe I interpreted wrong? About offending, in my opinion, people would get offended in the same way if I choose your answer instead of theirs.

Comment: @Guil can you post the link where this is stated?

Comment: @whosrdaddy [Here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, just make sure you check for errors on each call.

Fixed code:

```
var
  ffile : string;
  music: HSAMPLE; 
  ch: HCHANNEL;
  opendialog1 : topendialog;

begin 
 if not Dynamic_Bass.Load_BASSDLL('Library/Bass.dll') then
  Exit;
 // change device to -1 which is the default device
 if Dynamic_Bass.BASS_Init(-1,44000,Bass_DEVICE_SPEAKERS,0,nil) then
  begin
   opendialog1 := topendialog.Create(nil);
   try
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
     begin
      ffile := OpenDialog1.FileName;
      music := BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, PChar(ffile), 0, 0, 3, BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS);
      if music <> 0 then
       begin
        ch := BASS_SampleGetChannel(music, False);
        if ch <> 0 then
         begin
          // omitted, see if the basics work   
          // BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_PAN, 0);
          // BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(ch, BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, 1);
          if not BASS_ChannelPlay(ch, False) then
           ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
         end
        else
         ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
       end
      else
       ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
     end;
   finally  
    OpenDialog1.Free;
   end;
  end
 else
  ShowMessage(inttostr(bass_errorgetcode));
end;
```

**UPDATE**

I should have seen this sooner, your code fails because `BASS_SampleLoad` expects the filename in ANSI format, [the documentation clearly mentions this](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_SampleLoad.html), since you have Delphi XE3 and Strings are Unicode, you must supply the `BASS_UNICODE` flag to indicate this.

so the `Bass_SampleLoad` line becomes:

```
music := BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, PChar(ffile), 0, 0, 3, BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS 
          or BASS_UNICODE);
```

**UPDATE2**

Per Sir Rufo's request:
I added an exception based error checking routine to make the code cleaner and debugging more straightforward.

```
function BASS_ErrorToString(BASS_ErrorCode : Integer) : String;

begin

 case BASS_ErrorCode of :
  0: Result := 'BASS_OK';
  1: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_MEM';
  2: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_FILEOPEN';
  3: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_DRIVER';
  4: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_BUFLOST';
  5: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_HANDLE';
  6: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_FORMAT';
  7: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_POSITION';
  8: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_INIT';
  9: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_START';
  14: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_ALREADY';
  18: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NOCHAN';
  19: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_ILLTYPE';
  20: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_ILLPARAM';
  21: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NO3D';
  22: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NOEAX';
  23: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_DEVICE';
  24: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NOPLAY';
  25: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_FREQ';
  27: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NOTFILE';
  29: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NOHW';
  31: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_EMPTY';
  32: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NONET';
  33: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_CREATE';
  34: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NOFX';
  37: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_NOTAVAIL';
  38: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_DECODE';
  39: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_DX';
  40: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_TIMEOUT';
  41: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_FILEFORM';
  42: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_SPEAKER';
  43: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_VERSION';
  44: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_CODEC';
  45: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_ENDED';
  46: Result := 'BASS_ERROR_BUSY';
 else
  Result := 'BASS_ERROR_UNKNOWN';
 end;
end;

procedure BassResultCheck(ResultCode : Integer);
begin
 if ResultCode = 0 then
  begin
   ResultCode := BASS_ErrorGetCode;
   raise Exception.CreateFmt('BASS error : %s(%d)', [BASS_ErrorToString(ResultCode), ResultCode]);
  end;
end;

procedure BassBoolCheck(const BoolResult : Boolean);
begin
 BassResultCheck(Integer(BoolResult));
end;

procedure PlaySample(const SampleFilename : String);

var
  Sample : HSAMPLE; 
  Channel: HCHANNEL;


begin 
 if not Dynamic_Bass.Load_BASSDLL('Library/Bass.dll') then
  raise Exception.Create('Could not load BASS DLL');
 // change device to -1 which is the default device
 BassBoolCheck(Dynamic_Bass.BASS_Init(-1,44000,Bass_DEVICE_SPEAKERS,0,nil);
 Sample := BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, PChar(SampleFilename), 0, 0, 3, BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS OR BASS_UNICODE);
 BassResultCheck(Sample);
 Channel := BASS_SampleGetChannel(Sample, False);
 BassResultCheck(Channel);
 BassBoolCheck(BASS_ChannelPlay(Channel, False));
end;
```

Comment: Output 2, as in the question anyway. At `music <> 0` condition.

Comment: @SirRufo: very much agreed, but that is not the point here :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy, you can [`answer it here`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6778) as well :-)

Comment: @TLama: WOuld it be fun if I threw my answer into Google Translate? ;)

Comment: @whosrdaddy, definitely! Though I'm not sure if they'll get the code then :-)

Comment: Just did it! Offcourse I did not put the code into GT, that would be a  mess :)

Comment: I had recent issues in GT simply translating English to German. I had to revise my English text like 20 times before it would finally produce a proper legible translation.

Comment: I love that feeling to get 100 *pontos* for nothing :-) You got my *voto* even there.

Comment: I would upvote again, but I already had - the question was already well answered in first place. Now it is a gem :)

Comment: Look the guys interacting with portuguese e.e

Comment: @whorsedaddy I'll test it here.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I never studed(?) text formats at all. I normally know that stuff must be studed when someone tells me that I did wrong there. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @Guil no need to apologize here! One golden rule, no one is never too old to learn something new each day ;)